# Selecionar um select pelo valor digitado no input

Tags: javascript, html

Bom, vamos lá, acredito que minha duvida seja simples mas não consigo desenrolar.

```
<h2 style="color:#333333; font-family:verdana;font-size:100%;text-align:center">Código de Cliente:


<input type="text" id="codigocliente" /></h2>


<label for="lista">lista</label>
<select name="lista" id="lista" disabled="disabled">
  <option>Digite seu CPF</option>
  <option value="b3cdb2_353be7884bbf44488145b33338c03e52~mv2">12345678</option>
  <option value="b3cdb2_0bb5060e934b4896a8d78974355254d8~mv2">00000000</option>

</select>

</label>
<h3 style="text-align:center">    
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="window.open('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/' + document.getElementById('lista').value + '.jpg')" ><span>Acessar</span></button>
</h3>
```

Tenho esse scrypt, gostaria que o select selecionasse automaticamente o valor pelo valor digitado no input. Tipo, se no input o cliente digitar o valor 00000000, o selected mude automaticamente para esse valor, caso não exista, exibir um alerta dizendo que o valor não existe.

Deixei o selected desabilitado porque não quero exibir a lista de valores, só quero que o cliente digite no input e que o selected selecione o valor se ele existir ou mande uma mensagem dizendo que o valor não existe.

Assim que o valor do selected é selecionado, tem um botão ao qual redireciona ele para uma imagem ou arquivo especifico.

Comment: Pesquise sobre a função each() do JQuery, isso pode te ajudar.

Comment: [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem vindo ! podemos fazer usando `js` observe:

```js
$('#input').keyup(function(){

  var input = document.getElementById("input").value; //pega o valor digitado.

  if (input == '000' || input == '111' || input == '222') { //verifica se é o valor de sua preferencia. se for seleciona.
    
     //seleciona o elemento de acordo com o text do select
    $("#lista option:contains('"+input+"')").attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
  //coloco o length para pegar uma quatidade minimade caracteres para não mandar o alert direto
  if(input.length == 3 && input != '000' && input != '111' && input != '222'){
    alert("valor não existente. tente novamente!");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input"></input>

<select name="lista" id="lista" class="form-control">
<option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
    <option value="888888">000</option> 
    <option value="999999">111</option>
    <option value="777777">222</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Boa tarde amigo, ficou perfeito esse código, só tem um pequeno problema, ele pesquisa o resultado no valor do select, sendo que precisaria buscar o nome dele, tipo. <option value="888888">000</option> . nesse exemplo, ele deveria buscar pelo 000 e não pelo 888888. como faço essa alteração?

Comment: Corrigido ! alterei a linha que seleciona o elemento pelo `value`. agora ele seleciona pelo `text` do `select`

Comment: Ficou perfeito agora. Muito obrigado !!!

Comment: Que bom ! De uma olha aqui [Como aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 0):

A solução é simples, insira o código abaixo em seu JavaScript, mas não se esqueça de colocar as referências do JQuery no header do seu código.

```
$(function(){
    var existeCpf = false;

    $('#id_do_input').keyup(function(){
        verificaCpf($(this).val());
    });

    function verificaCpf(_valor){
        $('#lista').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == _valor){
                $(this).val(_valor);
                existeCpf = true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Basicamente o que eu fiz foi rodar o seu combobox e verifiquei se há algum valor igual o que foi digitado, se possui, ele irá selecionar e alterar a variável *existeCpf* para true, desta maneira você pode dar um alerta ao usuário.

Observações: Antes de colar este código, altere os *values* de seu combobox para os valores reais dos CPFs.